# Replacement for <conio.h> in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, compatibility

I need  to transfer a windows C++ project to linux, however I am currently using MS `<conio.h>`
 which is not linux or standards compatible. What header do you recommend to replace it for use in Linux? I would prefer the answer is cross platform too.

Comment: <conio.h> is not standard on Win32 either;  for example both Microsoft and Borland compilers provided a header of that name, each containing different functions and interfaces.  So who's <conio.h> are we talking about here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541819/how-can-i-write-an-ansi-c-console-screen-buffer/1541924#1541924

Comment: That is very much smaller than Borland's interface (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x2hy4cx%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), and much of it can be replaced with stdio or iostream functions.  Ignoring the port I/O functions that only work in Win95 in any case, `_kbhit()` and `_ungetch()` are the only functions not easily replaced with standard calls.  ncurses' `getch()` can be called with a timeout, which may be used to replace many uses of `_kbhit`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an replacement version of Conio.h for linux based on NCurses.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-conioh/

Comment: +1... So long as he was referring to Borland's conio and not Microsoft's!?

Comment: True, but the most used functions like coloring, gotoxy, etc. are same in both the Borland as the Microsoft implementation.

Comment: Neither colour not gotoxy exist in Microsoft's interface (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x2hy4cx%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) it is minimal compared with the Borland interface. However the Borland interface is almost a superset of Microsoft's, so this may indeed suit.

Answer (score 5):

You're going to want ncurses.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses